# Display message hello with "for" instead of "while"

Tags: python, for-loop

So my professor is saying that I can do this easier with 'for' instead of 'while' but I have no idea how to do it.

The code below output the message hello with the number it was inputed. another problem that I have is that the message hello is displayed going down is there a way to make it go from left to right.
Thanks and sorry for asking many question. I am just getting started doing coding.

````
pr_char = input('number to display?:')
h = [[1,0,0,0,1],
     [1,0,0,0,1],
     [1,1,1,1,1],
     [1,0,0,0,1],
     [1,0,0,0,1]]
i=0
while i < len(h):
    j=0
    while j<len(h[i]):
        if h[i][j] ==1:
            print(pr_char, end='')
        else:
            print(' ',end='')
        j = j + 1
    print()
    i = i+1

e = [[1,1,1,1,1],
     [1,0,0,0,0],
     [1,1,1,1,1],
     [1,0,0,0,0],
     [1,1,1,1,1]]
i=0
while i < len(e):
    j=0
    while j<len(e[i]):
        if e[i][j] ==1:
            print(pr_char, end='')
        else:
            print(' ',end='')
        j = j + 1
    print()
    i = i+1

l = [[1,0,0,0,0],
     [1,0,0,0,0],
     [1,0,0,0,0],
     [1,0,0,0,0],
     [1,1,1,1,1]]
i=0
while i < len(l):
    j=0
    while j<len(l[i]):
        if l[i][j] ==1:
            print(pr_char, end='')
        else:
            print(' ',end='')
        j = j + 1
    print()
    i = i+1

l1 = [[1,0,0,0,0],
     [1,0,0,0,0],
     [1,0,0,0,0],
     [1,0,0,0,0],
     [1,1,1,1,1]]
i=0
while i < len(l1):
    j=0
    while j<len(l1[i]):
        if l1[i][j] ==1:
            print(pr_char, end='')
        else:
            print(' ',end='')
        j = j + 1
    print()
    i = i+1

o = [[0,1,1,1,0],
     [1,0,0,0,1],
     [1,0,0,0,1],
     [1,0,0,0,1],
     [0,1,1,1,0]]
i=0
while i < len(o):
    j=0
    while j<len(o[i]):
        if o[i][j] ==1:
            print(pr_char, end='')
        else:
            print(' ',end='')
        j = j + 1
    print()
    i = i+1```
````

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A construct like

```
i = 0
while i < j:
    ...
    i += 1
```

is equivalent to

```
for i in range(0, j):
    ...
```

Comment: Beautiful answer... Simplicity at its best

Comment: At the risk of desimplifying it, I should add that the `while` loop can't modify `i` or `j` outside what is shown, and `i` has to be incremented in *every* iteration of the loop.

Comment: ah thanks!! also, may I know what I can do so the other letter goes to the right instead of going down?